# Youtube iframe API fails load or cue playlist

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I work with the Youtube Iframe API and when I try to use `player.loadPlaylist({list: 'PLAYLIST_ID'});` or `player.cuePlaylist({list: 'PLAYLIST_ID'});` the methods return the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tg' of null` since yesterday.

A few days ago, the method `cuePlaylist` stopped trigger the "video cued event' as it is explains in the [Youtube Iframe API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr#cuePlaylist)

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: The API seems to be working just fine ... http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/k7C82/ demonstrates. I assume that, in your post, it's just a typo that you forgot the {} around the list:'PLAYLIST_ID' (as the argument you pass needs to be an object)? If you posted your code, especially demonstrating where you're calling loadPlaylist (as it might be a scope issue), that could help.

Comment: The API just work if you load a single video first. If you want to start with a playlist, you have an error. You are right, I missed the brackets in the exemple, but they are in my source code.

Comment: My workaround didn't work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the same use case. You start with a single video (it's working), and I have to start with a playlist. the method to load and start a playlist is "loadPlaylist". this method worked 1 week ago. Not today :(

Comment: I'm not saying you replaca loadPlayList. You do that and then call playVideoAt(0). I agree with you that loadPlaylist was working a week ago. But now I load the playlist, then start playback with the first video on that playlist.

Comment: did u tried using `playlist` instead of `list`
`player.loadPlaylist({playlist: 'PLAYLIST_ID'});`

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it with calling

```
player.playVideoAt(0);
```

after calling `loadPlayList(...)`

Comment: Indeed this works. How did you come by that solution? Just a hunch?

Comment: I saw the playlist was loading but not starting, so added this method call.